# Parse facebook code param

Tags: facebook

I'm tring to authenticate with facebook using the following request:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MYAPPID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/oauth/callback.html&scope=email
```

The response is the following:

```
http://localhost:3000/oauth/callback.html?code=AQA6VzXu_In9_GIiqu-GFEo6d8sA4jM5L6rLQWtL9g2aMo2Ju5h9j_uCcqR-w7cYifyi0IYsOHtOk5S_jKBBlgQatybYDHOfSs2EpA3H3NHQIDIaKmC-9kje9_QQbhPd0Ge1pP-52OR7iOQWc_R8D-YapXcArTAmpIHLBHatOSHB0x3lFv4DVUECfb1IdYIZlVM#_=_
```

The problem is that I'm unable to retrieve an access token from this code. It should normally have a dot delimiter (".") whereas this has none, that's why I'm unable to decode it.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn'T be able to decode it, it's not a signed_request.

You need to send a request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
 client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
 client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_YOU_RECEIVED
```

in order to get an access token

Comment: Good catch. I was thinking that code is the same code (signed request) that facebook sends on each request on a facebook app or tab.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between CODE and TOKEN, both are very widely confused.

#### Client-side login (Javascript + HTML)

If you want to use javascript only (work with HTML only) as it is probably your case you should add `&response_type=token` to your first request.

Also, I don't think you actually need to split and work with the token but give the JS api to do it for you.

#### Server-side login (PHP)

You know have a user that a accessed your page with the CODE.
Now you must access, with your server-side script, this url and it will return the access_token.

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
     client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=CODE`

If your callback was a PHP you could just `filegetcontents` along with `json_decode` but I recommend using the official Facebook SDK.

Highly recommended doc page -
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/